ffmpeg subtitles filter defaults to Helvetica instead of specified font
I am trying to use a custom font in the subtitles of a video using ffmpeg, but despite my efforts, the font defaults to Helvetica. Here is the code I am using:
import ffmpeg
import os
import tempfile

def test_subtitle_font(font_path):

    # Simple arbitrary video and audio stream
    video = ffmpeg.input('color=color=black:size=640x360:duration=5', f='lavfi')
    audio = ffmpeg.input('anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:duration=5', f='lavfi')

    # Create arbitrary temp subtitle file
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False, suffix='.srt') as temp_subtitle_file:
        temp_subtitle_file.write("1\n00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:05,000\nThis is a test subtitle.")
    
    subtitle_file = temp_subtitle_file.name

    # Force style for font
    style = f"FontName=KOMIKAX_,FontFile={font_path},FontSize=24,Alignment=10"

    output_video_path = "subtitle_font_test.mp4"
    (
        ffmpeg
        .concat(
            video.filter('subtitles', filename=subtitle_file, force_style=style),
            audio,
            v=1, a=1
        )
        .output(output_video_path)
        .global_args('-report')
        .overwrite_output()
        .run()
    )

    # Remove the temp subtitle file
    os.remove(subtitle_file)

# Path to the font file
font_file_path = "./KOMIKAX_.ttf"

# Run the subtitle font test
test_subtitle_font(font_file_path)

Despite specifying the force_style parameter with the correct font path, the debug output shows that ffmpeg defaults to Helvetica:
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x11df1c860] fontselect: (KOMIKAX_, 400, 0) -> /System/Library/Fonts/Helvetica.ttc, -1, Helvetica 
I tried the following things as well

Specified FontFile with the full path to the font.
Ensured the font file exists and is readable.
Used different style parameters in force_style (putting .ttf in fontname, using fontsdir, etc.)

I know the font is valid because if I run this test code (in the same directory), the font shows up:
def test_font(font_path, text):
 
    video = ffmpeg.input('color=color=black:size=640x360:duration=5', f='lavfi')
    audio = ffmpeg.input('anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:duration=5', f='lavfi')
    
    video = video.drawtext(text=text, fontfile=font_path, fontsize=24, fontcolor='white', box=1, boxcolor='black@0.5', boxborderw=5, x='(w-text_w)/2', y='(h-text_h)/2')
    
    output_file = 'font_test_output.mp4'
    stream = ffmpeg.output(audio, video, output_file)
    ffmpeg.run(stream)


font_file_path = './KOMIKAX_.ttf'

# Run the font test
test_font(font_file_path, test_text)


Resolved. I fixed my issue by copying the Fontname exactly how it is written in font book, not the file itself (I am a Mac user).
